# Null source collection emptying destination collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm merging objects that have a List member. I'm telling AutoMapper to ignore null source members but when I merge in an object with a null collection, the destination get's an empty collection (even though it had items before the map).

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

```
        ConfigurationInfo template1 = new ConfigurationInfo() {
            Columns = null //1st templates list of columns is null
        };

        ConfigurationInfo template2 = new ConfigurationInfo() {
            Columns = new List<ColumnInfo>()
        };
        template2.Columns.AddRange(existingColumns); //template2.Columns.Count == 9

        ConfigurationInfo template3 = new ConfigurationInfo() {
            Columns = null //3rd templates list of columns is null
        };

        var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
            cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;

            cfg.CreateMap<ConfigurationInfo, ConfigurationInfo>()
                .ForAllMembers(option => {
                    //explicitly telling automapper to ignore null source members...
                    option.Condition((source, destination, sourceMember, destMember) => sourceMember != null);
                });

        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        ConfigurationInfo finalTemplate = new ConfigurationInfo();

        mapper.Map(template1, finalTemplate); 
        //finalTemplate.Columns == null, which is exptected
        mapper.Map(template2, finalTemplate); 
        //finalTemplate.Columns.Count == 9, still exptected
        mapper.Map(template3, finalTemplate); 
        //finalTemplate.Columns.Count == 0, expecting 9 b/c 3rd template.Columns == null so AutoMapper should ignore. why is this happening?
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with the same thing. There are a couple configurations that are supposed to solve this very issue but they don't work in my case. Maybe they will work for you.

In this case its in global configuration.

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
      cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
      cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
}
```

Here is the feature request I created in their repo. They do suggest some work arounds that might help you.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2341

Also, the check that you have for null source properties wont work for value types. You have to check for null or default. For that part I have created an extension:

```
public static bool IsNullOrDefault(this object obj)
{
    return obj == null || (obj.GetType() is var type && type.IsValueType  && obj.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(type)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override mapping for IEnumerable.

```
public class IgnoringNullValuesTypeConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<T, T> where T : class
{
    public T Convert(T source, T destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source ?? destination;
    }
}

cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable, IEnumerable>().ConvertUsing(new IgnoringNullValuesTypeConverter<IEnumerable>());
```

In this case it will work, but it is not universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting `AllowNullCollections` in [the mapper configuration initialization](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#handling-null-collections), you have the option to set `AllowNullCollections` in the mapper `Profile`, like this:

```
public class MyMapper : Profile
{
    public MyMapper()
    {
        // Null collections will be mapped to null collections.
        AllowNullCollections = true;

        CreateMap<MySource, MyDestination>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My best solution to this was to filter out the null properties before the mapping in an ExpandoObject and than map the expando to the destination.

```
        var patchTemplate = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

        foreach (var property in updatedTemplateDetails.GetType().GetProperties())
            if (property.GetValue(updatedTemplateDetails) is var propertyValue && propertyValue != null )
                patchTemplate.Add(property.Name, propertyValue);

        Mapper.Map(patchTemplate, finalTemplate);
```